# Chart.js. Values in a big range. The smallest values are not available

Tags: javascript, math, chart.js

I use Chart.js (http://www.chartjs.org) to show traffic usage for different units using Bar Chart. If I have big range of usage (1 unit 2.5GB, 2 unit 2.5MB, 3 unit 2.5kB, 4 unit 0B) smallest values are not available (I cannot hover over or click on them) when bring them to one value, say to the GB (2.5,0.0024,2.38E-6,...,0) or MB (2560,2.5,0.0024,...,0). Please all ideas how to display them on one chart to maintain the proportions and the ability to click and hover over on each Bar (even 0)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Example of the issue here http://jsfiddle.net/1zk86hz7/ (hover over out of order for last items)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ability to click and hover over on each Bar

Unfortunately, bars don't have a pointHitDetectionRadius equivalent. But you can override the inRange function for Chart.Rectangle to give a little more vertical detection range.

```
Chart.Rectangle.prototype.inRange = function (chartX, chartY) {
    return (chartX >= this.x - this.width / 2 && chartX <= this.x + this.width / 2) && (chartY >= this.y && chartY <= (this.base + 5));
};
```

I've extended the vertical area 5 units downward from the x axis, but you could change it to above the axis as well (just subtract it from this.y)

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/etLfr9ka/

> Please all ideas how to display them on one chart

As long as you don't set barShowStroke to false you would see a stroke for even 0 values.

The alternative would be pick a framework that supports logarithmic scales or one that allows you to split the y scale into sections - however IMO this would be a bad idea.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @potatopeelings. With regards to click/hover over for big bar I have no problem. I have issues when bars are too small. I would like to have bars not less then several pixels even if it should be much less. How to choose Value for y in smart way for little values?

Comment: the fiddle has a line even if the value is 0. In your code make sure you do NOT set barShowStroke to false.

Comment: please try this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1zk86hz7/. hover over out of order for last items. There are changed labels (for short (horizontal) labels it works) and my real data.

Comment: Sorry, didn't quite get what you wanted. Here is the modified fiddle with the above override applied - https://jsfiddle.net/njgq3hdr/. I am able to see the tooltips. If you want to increase the height of bars (and this would give a very wrong representation), you can increase the values and then override tooltip to show the actual value (without the increase you added), or you could set barStrokeWidth to a higher value (don't forget to set strokeColor)